# R data table updating columns with .SD and .SDcols in a single line of code

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
X <- data.table(
    A1 = 1:3 %>% as.character,
    A2 = 1:3 %>% as.character,
    B1 = 1:3 %>% as.character,
    B2 = 1:3 %>% as.character
)
```

The goal is to convert to numeric the `A`'s (e.g. `A1`, `A2`) variables from `X` using `.SD` and `.SDcols` in a single line of code.

Given that the following operation correctly returns the targeted variables' name:

```
> X[, (names(.SD)), .SDcols = names(X) %like% "A"]
[1] "A1" "A2"
```

I attempted to update them directly:

```
X[, (names(.SD)) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = names(X) %like% "A"]
```

But it unexpectedly returns an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(X, , `:=`((names(.SD)), lapply(.SD, as.numeric)),  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
```

I figured out that this 2 line code solution works:

```
.cols <- names(X) %like% "A"
X[, (names(X)[.cols]) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = .cols]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `.SD` and `.SDcols` in a single line of code?

Comment: `X[, grep("A", names(X), value = TRUE) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = grep("A", names(X), value = TRUE)]`? (note that this make determination of A-columns redundant and, imo, less readable)

Comment: @docendodiscimus It works indeed, but as you say it make the names redudant

Comment: So what is your intention here? If it's just an acamdic exercise, my comment demonstrates that it is possible to do it but if you want to use it in production code, I'd advise not to do so. 'Single-liners' aren't necessarily good code that's easy to understand and maintain and also efficient.

Comment: @docendodiscimus you can post your answer I'll accept it

Comment: If you're using magrittr, maybe this is a little more readable `grep("A", names(X), value = TRUE) %>% { X[, (.) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=.] }`